# Extra precision required for the implementation of trig functions with BigDecimal

Tags: java, precision, trigonometry, bigdecimal

#### Introduction

I am interested in writing math functions for `BigDecimal` (actually, also for 
[my own `BigDecimal` type](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/bigdecimals.html) written in Delphi, 
but that is irrelevant here -- in this question, I use Java's `BigDecimal` because more people know it and 
my `BigDecimal` is very similar. The test code below is in Java and works fine and works equally well in the Delphi
translation).

I know that `BigDecimal` is not fast, but it is pretty accurate. I do not want to use some existing Java `BigDecimal` math library, especially not 
because this is for my own `BigDecimal` type (in *Delphi*) as well.

As a nice example of how to implement trig functions, I found the following simple example (but I forgot where, sorry). It obviously uses 
MacLaurin series to calculate the cosine of a BigDecimal, with a given precision.

#### Question

This **precision** is exactly my problem. The code below uses an extra precision of 5 to calculate the result and only in the end, it rounds that down to the desired precision.

I have a feeling that an extra precision of 5 is fine for, say, a target precision up to 50 or even a little more, but not for `BigDecimals` with a much higher precision (say, 1000 digits or more). Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to verify this (e.g. with an online extremely accurate calculator).

**Finally, my question: am I right -- that 5 is probably not enough for larger numbers -- and if I am, how can I calculate or estimate the extra precision required?**

---

Example code calculates `cos(BigDecimal)`:

```
public class BigDecimalTrigTest 
{
    private List _trigFactors;
    private int _precision;
    private final int _extraPrecision = 5; // Question: is 5 enough?

    public BigDecimalTrigTest(int precision) 
    {
        _precision = precision;
        _trigFactors = new Vector();
        BigDecimal one = new BigDecimal("1.0");
        BigDecimal stopWhen = one.movePointLeft(precision + _extraPrecision);
        System.out.format("stopWhen = %s\n", stopWhen.toString());
        BigDecimal factorial = new BigDecimal(2.0);
        BigDecimal inc = new BigDecimal(2.0);
        BigDecimal factor = null;
        do 
        {
            factor = one.divide(factorial, precision + _extraPrecision,
                    BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);            // factor = 1/factorial
            _trigFactors.add(factor);
            inc = inc.add(one);                           // factorial = factorial * (factorial + 1)   
            factorial = factorial.multiply(inc);
            inc = inc.add(one);                           // factorial = factorial * (factorial + 1)  
            factorial = factorial.multiply(inc);
        } while (factor.compareTo(stopWhen) > 0);
    }

    // sin(x) = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7! + x^9/9! - ... = Sum[0..+inf] (-1^n) * (x^(2*n + 1)) / (2*n + 1)!
    // cos(x) = 1 - x^2/2! + x^4/4! - x^6/6! + x^8/8! - ... = Sum[0..+inf] (-1^n) * (x^(2*n)) / (2*n)!

    public BigDecimal cos(BigDecimal x) 
    {
        BigDecimal res = new BigDecimal("1.0");
        BigDecimal xn = x.multiply(x);
        for (int i = 0; i < _trigFactors.size(); i++) 
        {
            BigDecimal factor = (BigDecimal) _trigFactors.get(i);
            factor = factor.multiply(xn);
            if (i % 2 == 0) 
            {
                factor = factor.negate();
            }
            res = res.add(factor);
            xn = xn.multiply(x);
            xn = xn.multiply(x);
            xn = xn.setScale(_precision + _extraPrecision, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        }
        return res.setScale(_precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        BigDecimalTrigTest bdtt = new BigDecimalTrigTest(50);
        BigDecimal half = new BigDecimal("0.5");

        System.out.println("Math.cos(0.5) = " + Math.cos(0.5));
        System.out.println("this.cos(0.5) = " + bdtt.cos(half));
    }

}
```

#### Update

A test with Wolfram Alpha for `cos(.5) to 10000 digits` (as @RC commented) gives the same result as my test code for the same precision. Perhaps 5 *is enough as extra precision*. But I need more tests to be sure.

Comment: wolfram alpha is pretty precise for cos, see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos(12)+to+1000+digits

Comment: Ah, thanks, I will try to check my results with Wolfram Alpha. Good tip!

Comment: Solely an idea: If you do symbolic calculation, you can have lazily evaluated (infinite) series, combine them, have an error precision with every series, and maybe receive faster results. Using java 8 lambdas.

Comment: Hmmm... wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos(0.5)+to+1000+digits (and setting radians) gives me exact the same output as my test code with precision 1000, so in this example, 5 is enough. Must try even more digits and many different values. I assume that input values should not be too far away from 0 either.

Comment: @Joop: Thanks for the suggestion, but as I wrote, this should be translatable to Delphi as well, and use BigDecimal.

Comment: FWIW, the results are the same for 10,000 digits too. I didn't expect this.

Comment: @Joop: one of my next steps is the implementation of `BigRational` in Delphi. I guess that should be pretty accurate too. But I will keep symbolic (lazily evaluated) math in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce numbers not in -pi>x>=pi to that range.  The Taylor expansion for sin(x) gets less accurate as abs(x) increases, so reducing x down to this range will increase your accuracy for large numbers.

Comment: I know that. But even then, I still don't know if, say, 5 extra digits are enough. The same for the calculation of pi. To reduce the value to that range, I must have an at least equally precise value of pi.

Comment: you could try converting to degrees, correcting range, and then converting back to radians, but that itself could lead to some correction errors.

Comment: To get the precision, converting to degrees would still require a pi of the same precision. So for a precision of, say, 10000, I would have to have a pi in that range too (precision plus 5 -- or whatever --, just to be sure).